# Magento 2 : How to get data from cms block into a js file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, static-block

I have created a cms block in backend with the id *wsmaterial*. I have a modal that is created in a JavaScript file and the content for the modal should be the html from the cms block. Right now, it displays the id (*wsmaterial*) of the cms block, not the content.

In my features.js file:

```
var description = extendedOptionsConfig[option_id]['description'];
console.log(description);  // => displays 'wsmaterial'
```

Instead of *wsmaterial* I want to get the content of the block with the id *wsmaterial*. Something like this:

```
var description = <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('wsmaterial')->toHtml();?>
```

Is there any way of getting the content of the cms block in JS by the identifier?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to call some js content/file on the html element of that backend block file?

Comment: Update the code

Comment: add code here that you tried

Comment: I have updated the question.